# Custom Openssh Shell

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, shell

The environment is Ubuntu Server 12.04

I would like to create a user on a server that is only able to ssh into a shell that runs tail -f on a log file and closes the session once the program ends (ctrl+c).

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To be pedantic, it won't be ctrl+c, but `SIGHUP` (closer to ctrl+d) that kills the app.

You can put essentially whatever you want in the user's shell in `/etc/passwd`.  Simply replace the default on the user's passwd line (probably `/bin/bash`) with another program.  That program can be a script, such as `/usr/bin/tail_log_file`, with these contents, owned by root:root, with umode 0755:

```
#!/bin/rbash
tail -f /path/to/logfile
```

You can use some interpreter other than rbash, but it is advisable to use a restricted shell in such cases.

To be extremely pedantic about it, you should add the script's path to `/etc/shells`, but I usually find it works anyway.

Keep in mind also that the user could potentially put the script in the background, or use some options (`ssh username@host bash`) and still acquire a shell.  If you want to restrict the user in such ways, good filesystem permissions are the only real solution.

Comment: works great, thanks so much for your quick and accurate reply.

Comment: The only reason you would want to add something to `/etc/shells` is to allow users that have something else as their shell to set their shell to this; the superuser (`root`) can always change anyone's shell to anything they want.

Comment: To add what @JonathanCallen said: it's actually a security leak to add that script to `/etc/shells` as that would allow the user to change his shell (because `/usr/bin/tail_log_file` would then be considered an "unrestricted shell")!

Comment: Ok I will remove.

Comment: That is much too complicated; forced commands (see the answer by @tink) are the way to do it.

Answer (score 10):

ssh forced commands spring to mind if you're happy to use keypair based authentication.

```
man authorized_keys
/command=
```

Answer (score 2):

You can configure ssh to run a command of your choice when you log in using public key authentication. To do this, generate a pair of keys:

```
djs@sardinia:~$ ssh-keygen -f restricted-key 
Generating public/private rsa key pair. 
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): 
Enter same passphrase again: 
Your identification has been saved in restricted-key. 
Your public key has been saved in restricted-key.pub. 
The key fingerprint is: b1:8f:26:47:c2:c5:f2:8d:ed:a0:c4:bd:9a:30:9d:08 djs@sardinia 
[...]
```

`restricted-key.pub` contains a line suitable for putting in the users's `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file:

```
ssh-rsa AAAA...UDz47Nl djs@sardinia
```

but you can add a command to this, and ssh will run that command when logging in with the key:

```
command="tail -f /my/interesting/file" ssh-rsa AAAA...UDz47Nl djs@sardinia
```

Then the user can ssh to the machine using `ssh -i restricted-key`.